# How to disable monitor wake-up with mouse?

Tags: windows-10

If there is no input after a certain period of time, the monitor automatically enters the power saving mode.

In this situation, I would like to wake up the monitor's power saving mode only with keyboard input.

The monitor turns on when the mouse is touched even though the device manager's `Allow this device to wake the computer from standby mode` is turned off.

How can I turn off the monitor's wake-up function with the mouse?

```
에디션 Windows 10 Pro
버전  20H2
설치 날짜   ‎2021-‎05-‎12
OS 빌드   19042.985
경험  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit]() your post and add the output in the Command Prompt (cmd) of the command `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`. Try also to disable "Allow this device to wake the computer" for the keyboard. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified once it's done.)

Comment: @harrymc The keyboard should be used when wake up, should I disable it?

Comment: There were reports for your model that keyboard and mouse wakes were mixed-up in some weird ways. You may need to experiment. As regarding your `powercfg` output, unfortunately I can't read it.

Comment: @harrymc `powercfg` is HID keyboard dvice

Answer (score 1):

Launch the Device Manager.
Go to Mice and other pointing devices.
If you’re using a Bluetooth mouse, go to Human Interface Devices.
Right-click on your mouse and select Properties.
Select the Power Management tab.
Locate this option: Allow this device to wake the computer. Then uncheck it.

[source](https://www.technipages.com/stop-mouse-from-waking-up-windows-10-pc)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pm1JC3A
already done... but problem still not solved